# CSS Text over image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put text over an image like so:

```css
.gallery-image {
  position: relative;
}
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
h2 span {
  color: white;
  font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-image">
  <a href="#">
    <img src="image.jpg" width="280">
  </a>
  <h2><span>Text</span></h2>
</div>
```

but my text goes behind the image, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: Your code works fine I don't see the text over the img ... but if it's the case use @MelanciaUK suggestion

Comment: With (or even apparently without) a valid image src, the text appears on top of the image for me.

Comment: z-index. Give the text a higher index than the image.

Comment: Span tags are redundant with how you are using them. You could just apply the styling to the h2 itself, or add a class to the h2, but to add a new tag entirely is just a waste.

Comment: what browser were/are you using to display this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snippet is working for me, anyway:

- Give the `img` a `z-index: 2;`
- And the `h2` a `z-index: 3;`

Comment: I upvoted you because you suggested realistic `z-index` numbers. I hate seeing `9999999` and such, like there's realistically going to be another `9999998` elements stacked underneath that one -_-.

Comment: You're right about one thing: the example is fine. but the `image` is not being positioned, so a `z-index` is not going to do anything, for example, in this fiddle `img` has `z-index` of 4, `h2` has one of 2, nothing changes: [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qba7htoc/)

Comment: As already mentioned "For a **positioned** box, the 'z-index' property specifies" Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
h2 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  background: darkgray;
  padding: 1%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt="" />
  <h2>THIS text</h2>
</div>
```

Something like this? I've just styled the h2 tag, removing the need for that span tag you were using, and reducing markup.

Comment: @jmore009: I was actually just testing that (by replacing their image.jpeg).

Answer (score 0):

I feel this needs some explanation.

The example is working, but if it is in fact not working for OP, he/she *can* use `z-index` but simply calling `z-index` on the `img` tag is not going to work as [**demonstrated here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qba7htoc/). Changing the `z-index` of both the image and `h2` will have no effect.

[**z-index**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#z-index) only works on positioned elements. Since the parent element is `position:relative` you can use `position: inherit` on one of it's children (or simply set a position). In this case the `img` is wrapped in an anchor tag:

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="image.jpg" width="280">
 </a>
```

So applying a `z-index` to the `img` tag doesn't make sense anyways. Instead add it to the `a`:

```
a{
  position: inherit;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Now if you change the `z-index` values of `h2` and `a` you will see the element with the higher `z-index` number come forward:

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qba7htoc/2/)